# What log would show what in Windows blocked a programs' access to the Internet?

Tags: windows-7, security, internet-security

We have a program that connects to the internet to check registration for a subscription.

Something on a customer's computer is blocking that.

It's NOT:

1. Windows Firewall (I disabled it. Problem persisted). Set it to allow our program, restarted, problem persisted.
2. Malware Bytes (which is running). Did same testing as above.
3. Windows Live Essentials (again, same test as above).

I could not find any other security software running.

Testing I've done

1. They can get to the web page via the web browser
2. They can not get to the web page from within the program.
3. The program works fine on my site.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a router or IPS device that's doing it.

Comment: Try installing WireShark, see if the request is leaving the box and getting blocked on the network or if it is never even getting to the network adapter before getting blocked.

Comment: @BenN See my update:  the browser can get to the web page, but our program cannot. So I don't think it's something beyond the computer since anything beyond the computer should not (I think!) "know" whether the http request is coming from our program or a browser.

Comment: Does the network use a proxy which the browser would have configured, but your application does not?